# Make full dt dd draggable using jquery

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a jsfiddle on which i would like to make full dt content dragable.

how would i do that can any one please help me on this.

[JSFIDDEL](http://jsfiddle.net/5p2ynsLx/1/)

```
 <dl id="sortable1">
<dt class="ui-state-default">Title</dt>
<dd>Hello</dd>
<dt class="ui-state-default">Title</dt>
<dd>Hello</dd>
<dt class="ui-state-default">Title</dt>
<dd>Hello</dd>
<dt class="ui-state-default">Title</dt>
<dd>Hello</dd>
<dt class="ui-state-default">Title</dt>
<dd>Hello</dd>
<dt class="ui-state-default">Title</dt>
<dd>Hello</dd>
<dt class="ui-state-default">Title</dt>
<dd>Hello</dd>

</dl>
```

JS COde

```
     $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();

  } );
```

Comment: Please place the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to be able to drag the "Title" and "Hello" as one item?

If so just wrap each item in a div:

```
  <div>
    <dt class="ui-state-default">Title</dt>
    <dd>Hello</dd>
  </div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5p2ynsLx/2/